# Windows Batch File xcopy specific files from same folder

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a folder that I want to copy several but not all files from, and I am trying to work out how to use a macro for tidy code. For example, the source folder might have 50 files and I want to copy 15 of them, how do I do something like this:

```
Set SourceDir = "C:\Source Folder"
Set DestDir =   "C:\Destination Folder"

xcopy "%SourceDir%\staff.xlsx"   %TargetDir% /i /d /y
xcopy "%SourceDir%\regions.xlsx" %TargetDir% /i /d /y
xcopy "%SourceDir%\sales.xlsx"   %TargetDir% /i /d /y
```

Comment: Yes I do and thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: ok, see answer below.

Comment: There are several issues with what you've posted, this is what it should look like: **Line 1.** `@Set "SourceDir=C:\Source Folder"`, **Line 2.** `@Set "DestDir=C:\Destination Folder"`, **Line 4.** `@"%__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe" "%SourceDir%\staff.xlsx" "%DestDir%\" /DY`, **Line 5.** `@"%__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe" "%SourceDir%\regions.xlsx" "%DestDir%\" /DY`, and **Line 6.** `@"%__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe" "%SourceDir%\sales.xlsx" "%DestDir%\" /DY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the files you would like to copy, I would say a `batch-file` like this should do the trick. it can simply be saved in a `filename.cmd` format:

```
@echo off
Set "Source=C:\Source Folder"
Set "target=C:\Destination Folder"
set list="Staff.xlsx"^
         "regions.xlsx"^
         "some other file.xlsx"^
         "sales.xlsx"

for %%i in (%list%) do echo xcopy "%Source%\%%~i" "%Target%\" /i /d /y
pause
```

**Note** that there is an `echo` command before `xcopy` it is simply my debugging feature to ensure you `echo` the results to screen, instead of performing the actual task. Once you modified everything and you're happy with the result, you can remove the `echo` to perform the actual command.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.